# How to have an image on an image upload button with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is my current code and I want to have a button that's an image, where you can upload a design for a socks competition. Any Ideas?

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
          <Image source={{uri: image}} source={designIcon} style={styles.thumbnail}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will you take the picture locally or from the internet? If locally,

```js
<Image source={designIcon} style={styles.thumbnail}/>
```

or from URL,

```js
 <Image source={{uri: image}} style={styles.thumbnail}/>
```

Note:

1-) thumbnail style should has height

2-) If image in your locally, designIcon should be : designIcon = require('imagepath/img.png')

Comment: The designIcon is locally added and the uploaded image is to the internet/ firebase.